# ProgressBar working on emulator and not on phones

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I've got this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="56dp"
android:minWidth="56dp">
<ProgressBar android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

The spinning progressbar runs fine when i run my application in Droid4X emulator, but it doesn't show any spinning progressbar on my phone. Tried another phone too, no progressbar. Can you help me finding my problem? Thanks

To be precise it works on every API except 23.
To be even more precise, it works if i put

```
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code work fine on my phone, I think the problem not in this code.

Answer (score 0):

It is also working on my Android Moto G. And there is if problem persists than do not run on emulator rather connect your phone with Android studio and enable

*Developer Mode*

and than select device as your phone. If any problem will be it will debug.